# How to boot a KVM virtual machine raw image to VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mount, qemu, linux-kvm

I have received a .img file of a server which is a Virtual Machine running in a KVM environment.  The Virtual Machine was installed with Ubuntu.

I would now like to take this .img file and "emulate" the server within VirtualBox.  So I have converted the .img file to a .vdi file using qemu-img from raw to vdi, however the VirtualBox instance starts up and simply states:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

I do not know if I would have to install KVM in VirtualBox and then configure it to run the VM in my .img file, or if I would be able to convert the image from KVM to VDI and then just run the server in VirtualBox directly.

What I have tried already is using qemu to convert the .img raw file to a .vdi, but that produced the above errors.

I have also read the answer [on this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/573582/migrate-kvm-img-to-virtualbox-vdi), but this question is slightly different, as it is talking about moving a Windows VM from KVM to VirtualBox.

I have also tried converting from qcow2 to vdi using the qemu-img linux package, however I continually get the following error messages:

```
#> qemu-img convert -f qcow2 original.img -O vdi converted.vdi
qemu-img: Could not open './duketest.img': Invalid argument
qemu-img: Could not open './duketest.img'
```

I have also tried converting using the VBoxManage command as shown on this page:

http://funcptr.net/2012/04/01/converting-kvm-virtual-machines-to-virtualbox/

This also provides the error message I mentioned at first:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @stbonearth don't worry, this is a perfectly appropriate question as currently worded. Hopefully somebody will be able to provide an answer for you soon.

Comment: I don't think KVM will install in virtualbox since KVM needs VT-X support to run. I do have copies of both so I'll see if I can test.

Comment: Just so I can replicate the environment in case my answer is missing something - what specific distro does this server run?

Answer (score 9):

There's a few small issues with your conversion stanza.

`qemu-img convert -f qcow2 original.img -O vdi converted.vdi` tells you to explicitly convert a qcow2 file to a VDI, and you have an raw image file. You essentially told your computer to translate a french text, using a spanish translator, into english.

You are better off with `qemu-img convert -O vdi original.img original.vdi` - letting qemu decide what's the format of the input *implicitly*. If you *must*, I believe the right input format for a img is raw, not qcow.

I've tested using the command I used in conversion from  from qcow2 to VDI and and from a raw file to a VDI it works. (Interestingly qcow2 to raw to VDI dosen't.)

Just to confirm what I did

1. Create a VM with libvirt-manager with a qcow or img disk image
2. Install Ubuntu Minimal
3. Check if the system boots
4. Use qemu-image with qemu-img convert -O vdi original.ext original.vdi for both files
5. Move the file over to a windows/virtualbox system
6. Check to see if it boots.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but here we are in 2021 and this actually worked for me.  I downloaded my raw KVM img file onto Windows 10, ran qemu-img for Windows to convert it to vdi, and opened it in virtualbox on Windows 10.  Brilliant!

Comment: Well - at this point, they are fundamental/common tools. No reason to change what's not broken :D